# Separate local logger with root log python

Tags: python, logging

I am using logging module in python. In my `main.py` file I am using two logger.

1. Root logger (To get logs from multiple modules in same directory)
2. Local logger (To log specific information)

I want information of `local logger` to be separate from `root logger`. But when I am creating separate logger. Information of `local logger` is also present in root logger info.

Here is the sample of how I am doing this

```
# main.py
import logging

def setup_logger(filename, name = ''):
    if name == '':
        logging.basicConfig(filename=filename,
                            format='%(asctime)s %(funcName)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                            filemode='a')
        logger = logging.getLogger()
    else:
        """
        handler = logging.FileHandler(filename, mode = 'a')
        handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(funcName)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'))
        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
        """
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
        handler = logging.FileHandler(filename)
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.addHandler(handler)

        return logger
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    return logger

logger = setup_logger('main.log')
local_logger = setup_logger('local_log.log', 'local_log')
```

```
# other file under root log
logger = logging.getLogger("__main__." + __name__)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [logger hierarchy](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial), and how your loggers relate to the root logger?

Comment: yeah, I want local_logger to be independent of log hierarchy. But somehow it is relating to root_logger. I am not sure how to differentiate those two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to stop propagation if you don't want the local loggers to send their logs to the root loggers handlers:

```
logger.propagate = False
```

This part of the documentation explains it well: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow